# SQL Server view return 0.00

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three selects in my view:

```
Create view myView
As
Begin
    Select Col1, Col2, Col3 from table1
    Union
    Select Col1, Col2, Col3 from table2
    Union
    Select 0.00 As Col1, 0.00 As Col2, 0.00 As Col3 from table3
End
```

If I query:

```
Select 0.00 As Col1, 0.00 As Col2, 0.00 As Col3 
from table3
```

It returns `0.00` for all three columns, but when I query the view

```
Select * from myView
```

It returns "0" instead of 0.00 for the third select. Anything missing here?

My mistake, I entered in comment that the datatype is decimal, actually all the columns (col1,Col2,Col3) in table1 and table2, has "float" datatype.
Type :float, computed:  no,Length:  8

EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT * FROM myView;'
gives

```
Name | IsNullable | system_type_id | system_type_name |max_length|precision|scale
Col1 | 1    |62 |float  |8  |53 |0
Col2 | 1    |62 |float  |8  |53 |0
Col3 | 1    |62 |float  |8  |53 |0
```

Comment: What is Col1, Col2, Col3 from table1 and table2?

Comment: Can you put a sample schema for table 1 , table 2 , just interested in data types been used

Comment: What are the **datatypes** of your `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3` ?? If any of the columns is an `INT`, then SQL Server will convert all values from any of the `SELECT` ni the `UNION` to `INT` (thus removing your `.00` ...)

Comment: Could it be that in the other tables the column types are `int` or any other non-fractional type?

Comment: @marc_s, since decimal has a higher precedence than int, I would expect the int values to be converted to decimal rather than visa-versa.

Comment: Please include the columns datatype in your question too

Comment: Float has a higher datatype precedence than both int and decimal though, so that could explain the formatting.

Comment: in table and table 2 the datatype for col1,col2,col3 are decimal and in the result of the select for first two statement, it is giving me decimal values but not for third select

Comment: @marc_s, according the to Books Online (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx), data type precedence rules apply to UNION.  sp_describe_first_result_set shows this behavior.  I'm guessing this is a display issue.

Comment: @JohnyBravo, how are you viewing the results?

Comment: in sql only, "select * from myView", even in my application it is returning '0'

Comment: Float 0.00 is definetly formatted as 0 in SS MS output greed.

Comment: @JohnyBravo, when you say `SQL only`, do you mean SQL Server Management Studio?  I get the expected results with SSMS SQL 2016.  What are the results of `EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT * FROM myview;'`?

Comment: @serg ok, but in my mvc application also it is retrning 0, can I get 0.00 somehow

Comment: @JohnyBravo, you need format the value explicitly as desired. `String.Format()` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type returned by UNION is `float` due to data type precedence rules as documented in the [SQL Server Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx).  However, it is up to the application to render the value with or without decimals.  In the case of a .NET app, you can specify a format string for consistent display formatting.

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (
      col1 float
    , col2 float
    , col3 float
    );
CREATE TABLE table2
    (
      col1 float
    , col2 float
    , col3 float
    );
CREATE TABLE table3
    (
      col1 decimal(12, 2)
    , col2 decimal(12, 2)
    , col3 decimal(12, 2)
    );
INSERT  INTO dbo.table1
VALUES  ( 1.1, 0, 0 );
INSERT  INTO dbo.table3
VALUES  ( 0, 0, 0 );
GO

CREATE VIEW myview AS
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM table2
    UNION
    SELECT 0.00 As Col1, 0.00 As Col2, 0.00 As Col3 FROM table3;
GO

--shows 0 and 1.1
SELECT * FROM myview;

--shows float for result types
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT * FROM myview;';
GO
```

Comment: on application side I can manage, but I wonder why Sql is not giving 0.00 back, even when I am using CAST

Comment: Does this mean we will not get '0.00' from sql side

Comment: SQL is returning the float value in native (binary) format.  The value must be converted to a string for presentation and it is entirely up the application code to do that.  SSMS likes to suppress the decimal point and insignificant zeros for zero float values, which is not configuratable AFAIK.  But in your .NET code, you can use `yourFloat.ToString("0.00")` or similar to show decimals.

Answer (score -1):

Please provide the data type of the table 1 and table 2.

When you do the UNION multiple tables, it would union tables from left to right.

If the data type of Col1, Col2, Col3 of table1 and table2 are integer then,

you would get the result as integer.

If you want the result as you got in the first query, then create the view as follows

```
Create view myView
As
Begin
    Select 0.00 As Col1, 0.00 As Col2, 0.00 As Col3 from table3
    Union
    Select Col1, Col2, Col3 from table1
    Union
    Select Col1, Col2, Col3 from table2

End
```

Comment: for col1 in table1, I am getting value as 3.672

Comment: Yes I understand, that the precedence will take place, but I am not sure what is going wring here

Comment: taking the third select in first place, also returns '0', instead of '0.00'.

Comment: Can you try something like this Select CAST(0.00 as decimal(18,2)) As Col1, CAST(0.00 as decimal(18,2)) As Col2, CAST(0.00 as decimal(18,2)) As Col3 from table3 . Coz 0.00 is considered as integer and getting rounded to 0. If you explicitly cast to decimal you may overcome this issue

Comment: still not getting the expected result after using CAST(0.00 as decimal(18,2)) As Col1